calculateTopPadding() is 0.0
I have two Screens, the value of calculateToppadding in the first one is 0.0
fun HomeScreen(appState: AppState) {
Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { insets -\>
val safeTop = insets.calculateTopPadding()
Log.d("HomeContent", "safeTop:$safeTop")
HomeContent(appState)

    }

}


But the second Screens can get the status bar height
fun CitiesScreen(appState: AppState) {   
Scaffold(     
  Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { 
  val safeTop = it.calculateTopPadding()         
 Log.d("CitiesContent", "safeTop:$safeTop")}}


Why is there such a problem

And you are not using any topBar in both screens? Please edit your post and include more code.
